# How to measure a large number of components in React Native without causing an error?

Tags: javascript, performance, react-native, drag-and-drop, measure

I'm trying to implement a generic Drag-and-Drop module that I may or may not release on NPM.

I took inspiration from an already existing DnD module which consisted of essentially two main components: `Draggables` and `DropZones`.

The `Draggable` components would enable any content that they enclosed to be dragged around, and `DropZones` were the components that would react to when a `Draggable` component was dragged in/out of them and/or dropped onto them.

The module's functionality was too basic for what I needed, so I set off on making my own.

Everything has been going fine except for one aspect: measuring the absolute position of a **large number** of components in order to find their corresponding bounding shapes for collision detection.

Currently, I've been using the `View's` `measure` method to measure the absolute position and size of my components, however, if you call this method too many times within a short period of time, React Native will throw this error: `Warning: Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code` and it lists the offending method as `{"module":"UIManager","method":"measure"}`.

If I make a basic `for` loop that repeatedly calls the `measure` method, I can get it up to just over 500 iterations before React Native complains (this number may be hardware-dependent; I'm not sure).

Also, the same problem happens when using the `View's` other measuring methods (e.g. `measureInWindow`, `measureLayout`).

What's even worse is that up until now, I have been calling the `measure` method in a `View's` `onLayout` callback, however, I recently discovered that `onLayout` does **not** get called when a style changes that **doesn't directly affect** the given `View` (such as when a parent component's margin changes).

This means that the given components can be re-positioned (relative to the screen) without them knowing about it.

Because of this I will have to use a different means of notifying my components that they need to remeasure themselves.

I thought about using some of the life-cycle methods that pertain to component updates, but that would most likely be even worse, because most of them get called every time the component updates which is far more often than a layout happens.

**Edit:** One other problem with using the life-cycle methods that pertain to component updates is if a parent component prevents it's child components from being updated (such as through `shouldComponentUpdate`).

Comment: Have this exact same problem when trying to measure several `ref`s for impression tracking

Comment: @GeorgeJose - I'm not sure where the bottleneck is, but my best guess is that it probably has something to do with the Bridge (which allows your JS code to interact with the Native modules).  If this is the case, then I'm hoping that the upcoming re-architecture later this year will fix the problem, as it will allow the JS code to interact directly with the Native modules without the potential of bogging down the Bridge.